# How to slice items generated from a forloop with conditionals in django

Tags: django

I have a list of categories as well as a list of products my template is in such a manner that it has category sections each with a display of products that belong to said categories. I created a for loop for categories so as to easily display category sections for each category I create.  I then went on to create a forloop for products within the category forloop with a condition so as to match products with their actual category before they are displayed under their category section.  how can I slice the resulting products to limit the number of products shown

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image_263x629 = models.ImageField(upload_to='cat_imgs')
    image_263x629_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='cat_imgs')
    image_263x629_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='cat_imgs')
    img_array = [image_263x629, image_263x629_2, image_263x629_3]
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
    #   return reverse('subcat_detail', args=[str(self.id)])    

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image_182x182 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/')
    image_1200x1200 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_600x600 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_600x600_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_300x300 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    img_array = [image_1200x1200, image_600x600, image_600x600_2]
    sku = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = SubCategory
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()



    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all()
        context['pdts'] = Product.objects.order_by('?')[:12]
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['subcategories'] = SubCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```

Template

```
    {% for category in categories %}
        <div class="ps-block--products-of-category">
          <div class="ps-block__categories">
            <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>
            <ul>
              {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
              {% if subcategory.category.name == category.name %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'subcat_detail' subcategory.id %}">{{ subcategory.name }}</a></li>
              {% endif %}  
              {% endfor %}
            </ul><a class="ps-block__more-link" href="{% url 'cat_detail' category.id %}">View All</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ps-block__slider">
            <div class="ps-carousel--product-box owl-slider" data-owl-auto="true" data-owl-loop="true"
              data-owl-speed="7000" data-owl-gap="0" data-owl-nav="true" data-owl-dots="true" data-owl-item="1"
              data-owl-item-xs="1" data-owl-item-sm="1" data-owl-item-md="1" data-owl-item-lg="1" data-owl-duration="500"
              data-owl-mousedrag="off">
              <a href="#"><img src="{{ category.image_263x629.url }}" alt=""></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="{{ category.image_263x629_2.url }}" alt=""></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="{{ category.image_263x629_3.url }}" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ps-block__product-box">
              {% for product in products %}
                {% if product.category.category.name == category.name  %}
                  <div class="ps-product ps-product--simple">
                    <div class="ps-product__thumbnail"><a href="{% url 'pdt_detail' product.id %}"><img src="{{ product.image_300x300.url }}"
                          alt=""></a>
                      {% if product.discount > 0 %}  
                        <div class="ps-product__badge">-{{ product.discount }}%</div>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if product.available == False %}
                        <div class="ps-product__badge out-stock">Out Of Stock</div>
                      {% endif %}
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="ps-product__container">
                      <div class="ps-product__content" data-mh="clothing"><a class="ps-product__title"
                          href="{% url 'pdt_detail' product.id %}">{{ product.name }}</a>
                        <div class="ps-product__rating">
                          <select class="ps-rating" data-read-only="true">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="1">2</option>
                            <option value="1">3</option>
                            <option value="1">4</option>
                            <option value="2">5</option>
                          </select><span>01</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="ps-product__price sale">UGX{{ product.price }}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endif %}  
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please do *not* filter in the template. You should filter in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Please do *not* filter in the template. You should filter in the view. A template implements *rendering logic*, not business logic*.

You can filter and slice in the view with:

```
def my_view(request):
    # …
    products = Product.objects.filter(category__name='specified category')[:10]
    context = {
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

This is not only the place where filtering belongs, it is also more efficient since we here will filter and slice on the *database side*. Typically a database can do this more efficient, and it furthermore limits the bandwidth from the database to the Django/Python layer.

**Note** (based on [@SLDem's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381224/how-to-slice-items-generated-from-a-forloop-with-conditionals-in-django/65381323#comment115590205_65381323)):

If you aim to filter children, you make use of a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch). Indeed, imagine that we have a `QuerySet` of `Category`s and we want to only retain `Product`s that are available, we can use:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'product_set',
        Product.objects.filter(available=True),
        to_attr='available_products'
    )
)
```

then in the template we can render this with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for product in category.available_products %}
        …
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what if I'm looking to render a list of parent objects and with them a list of children objects for each parent, how can I implement that without filtering children objects in a template?

Comment: @SLDem: you do that with a `Prefetch` object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

Comment: @SLDem: I expanded the answer with an example how you can for example filter available products per `Category`.

Comment: beautiful, thank you very much, gonna use this now instead :)

Comment: I filtered in the template since the actual structure of my code in my template  is in the following format   That above stated code is also within a a for loop iterating through a category list , so the filter is there to  match products to the category item

Comment: @JordanRob: Why do you iterate wit two loops over the `category`s?

Comment: @JordanRob: I suggest that you edit your question, include *what* you aim to do and the current view. With the current state of the question, it is hard to tell how to solve the problem.

Comment: I do so since my template has category sections for which i decided to use a for loop to present , said category sections each have a display for products under them , so i used another forloop to show products that belong to said category

Comment: @JordanRob: but that does not exmplain why you have a `{% for category in categorys %}`, twice, nor does it explains why you filter in the template. You can simply pass two items to the template `categories` which includes all categories, and `filtered_categories` which filters it.

Comment: @JordanRob: but again, it will probably be a lot easier if you share your models and views, and explain what you aim to do. With the current limited data, only a suboptimal result is possible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry that was a typo its only one forloop for categories and one as well for products , alright let me edit the question